# Android Periodic Work Request Start and Stop when the app is starting and closing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background-service, android-workmanager, android-background

When my app is starting, I created a periodic work request using **WorkManager** to fetch the data from the server and its working fine. My problem is, I want to cancel the work request when my app is closing.

How to cancel the work request when my app is closing or how to detect the app is closing?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [1](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-detect-android-application-open-and-close-background-and-foreground-events-1b4713784b57) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865016/why-manage-lifecycle-through-application-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/cancel-stop-work).

> In Kotlin

```
WorkManager.cancelWorkById(workRequest.id)
```

> In Java

```
WorkManager.cancelWorkById(workRequest.getId());
```

> You can also cancel WorkRequests by tag using
>   WorkManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(String). Note that this method cancels
>   all work with this tag. Additionally, you can cancel all work with a
>   unique name using WorkManager.cancelUniqueWork(String).

**EDIT**

To check help in app closing events, check the [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner).

**Kotlin example**

https://github.com/jshvarts/AppLifecycleDemo

Comment: Yes. I know that. I want to know how to detect when the app is closing?

Comment: @stay_hungry are you using multiple activities?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576734/android-checking-whether-the-app-is-closed

Comment: @Rahul Khurana, Yes..I have several activities.

Comment: @RahulKhurana ,@ZaferCelaloglu... I think ProcessLifecycleOwner works for me.. I will check let you guy. Thanks

Comment: @stay_hungry did you got the chance to check the output?

Comment: @RahulKhurana, not yet.I will let u know once I check.. cheers

Comment: @RahulKhurana, I checked s ProcessLifecycleOwner. Its working fine.thanks

Answer (score 0):

To can work on app close, override Activity's `onDestroy()` method and then cancel the current work. There are mainly two types of work

**Enqueued Work**

If you no longer need your previously-enqueued work to run, you can ask for it to be cancelled. The simplest way to do this is by cancelling a single WorkRequest using its id and calling

```
WorkManager.cancelWorkById(workRequest.getId());
```

OR you can also cancel work by `tag`.

```
WorkManager.cancelAllWorkByTag(String)
```

**Running Work**

There are a few different reasons your running worker may be stopped by WorkManager:

- You explicitly asked for it to be cancelled (by calling WorkManager.cancelWorkById(UUID), for example).
- In the case of unique work, you explicitly enqueued a new WorkRequest with an ExistingWorkPolicy of REPLACE. The old WorkRequest is immediately considered terminated.
- Your work's constraints are no longer met.
- The system instructed your app to stop your work for some reason. This can happen if you exceed the execution deadline of 10 minutes. The work is scheduled for retry at a later time.

Under these conditions, your worker will receive a call to `ListenableWorker.onStopped()`.

According to your requirements, you explicitly asked for it to be cancelled (1st Point).
You need to override `onStopped()` in your worker class and perform cleanup.

```
@Override
public void onStopped() {
    super.onStopped();
    //Perform cleanup
}
```

And in your activity `onDestroy()` method, stop work by either `id` or `tag`.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    WorkManager.cancelWorkById(UUID);
}
```

Hope this will work. Thanks